# GNU Parallel as alternative to JMeter SSH sampler for SFTP testing for several users in separates threads

Tags: parallel-processing, sftp, gnu, jmeter-plugins, gnu-parallel

Has anyone created a script for connection testing sftp for multi users in separate threads?

I have an issue with JMeter and I'm trying to make an alternative to SSH sampler.
I'm going to create a simple script to connect the SFTP and execute a "ls" command.
Currently I try to use GNU parallel(Thanks @Barmar).
This command works fine:

```
parallel < list.txt
```

I created a list.txt with a list of commands:

```
sftp -i /rsa_key user@sftp_url.com <<< ls
sftp -i /rsa_key2 user2@sftp_url.com <<< ls
...
sftp -i /rsa_keyX userX@sftp_url.com <<< ls
```

But still I'm limited by the number of my physical cores.
Is it possible to make 100+ requests at the same time by different threads?

Comment: Bash doesn't have threads. You can run commands in the background with `&`, you can use GNU `parallel`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not clear does it support SFTP.
parallel -S '/rsa_key 'user@sftp_url.com echo custom ::: ssh
doesn't work

Comment: Parallel doesn't "support" anything in particular, it's a way to run multiple any command in multiple processes.

Comment: Can I ask you to show an example with sftp connection? I have a list of users with the same ssh key. I used a JMeter before, but looks like it has issue with proxy. I'm new to linux.

Comment: See examples here: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html

Comment: I used the example above from there. A bit confusing and unclear, especially when new to Linux. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you have trouble getting it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it. We won't write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for misunderstanding
I got success to use:  
seq 10 | parallel -n0 sftp -i /rsa_key user@sftp_url.com
Can I use a list of commands in the text file?
Something like this:  
parallel < commands.txt
and provide: 
sftp -i /rsa_key user@sftp_url.com & sftp -i /rsa_key user2@sftp_url.com & ...

Comment: I don't use parallel myself, I can't provide detailed answers like that.

Comment: But if the commands are all the same except for parameters, I don't see why you would do it that way. It already provides a way to substitute parameters into the command.

Comment: Please click [edit] and update your question so it properly reflects what you are asking rather than adding a bunch of comments. You can't expect folk to wade through a whole story in the comments - Stack Overflow works best when questions are clear, concise and complete. If you have a list/array of things, show a representative array. If you want to run multiple command in parallel, show the first 3-4 so we can deduce the pattern. Thank you.

Comment: Mmm... it's still not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What does `sftp user1@sftp.com` achieve?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
sftp -i /rsa_key user@sftp_url.com 
to connect to sftp using ssh rsa-key and user name

Comment: Ok, you connect and then what?

Comment: I just want to create multi connections in separate threads and use a simple command ls

Comment: So please click [edit] and show the actual commands you want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you cannot do:

```
parallel -j100 < list.txt
```

or:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' -j100 'sftp -i {1} {2}@sftp_url.com <<< ls' < list.txt
```

with list.txt containing:

```
/rsa_key user
/rsa_keyX userX
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Looks like GNU parallel can't run more threads than physical cores in the system, at least with sftp.

Comment: @3oJIoTou That sounds like a limitation in your system. It is not limited by GNU Parallel, and I can run 1500 simultaneous `sftp`s with no problem.